# MySQL's UTF-8 character support

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I am getting this exception
`java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x99 Adm...' for column` when trying to insert a value in MySQL table. I found that **\xC2\x99** maps to U+0099 (or \u0099) which is a 2-Byte character. From documentation, a character with 3 Bytes or less is supported by MySQL's UTF-8. I also read about utfmb4, but since this character is 2 Bytes and still giving this error, so the issue might be something else. Please suggest.

Comment: What is the encoding of the column/table into which you are trying to do the insert?

Comment: MySQL supports a large set of character sets and encodings but it doesn't try to guess anything. Your program must tell it the charset/encoding it wants to use for the connection. Read more about the [character set support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html) in MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry can you tell which exact field are you advising to check? I checked character_set_name for this table/column and it is latin1.

Comment: I believe he mean to check `collation` you are using for your particular column which is throwing error

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  COLLATION_NAME for this column: latin1_swedish_ci. Should I use some other? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the default collation `latin1_swedish_ci` whereas you should be using `utf8_general_ci` since you meant to store `UTF-8` data in the column. Check MySQL Documentation on [Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html)

You can use an `ALTER` command to change the collation character set

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: What confuses me is that U+0099 actually belongs to the ISO-8859-1 encoding. I had always assumed that MySQL would make the appropriate conversion.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, you mean automatic conversion? don't think so ... if it's a select statement then we can ask the column result to be collated in a specific character set but for `INSERT` am really not sure.

Comment: It certainly does. I use UTF-8 clients to successfully store and retrieve data in tables with all kind of collations. Whatever, I've just remembered a strange fact that can explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Character [U+0099](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/charset_support.htm) (aka `'<control>'`) can indeed be [encoded in Latin-1 aka ISO-8859-1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/charset_support.htm) (more specifically, it's `0x99`) and your connection appears to be properly configured to use UTF-8.

I suspect the problem is a MySQL peculiarity: [`latin1` does not mean `ISO-8859-1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html):

```
mysql> SHOW CHARACTER SET like 'Latin1';
+---------+----------------------+-------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description          | Default collation | Maxlen |
+---------+----------------------+-------------------+--------+
| latin1  | cp1252 West European | latin1_swedish_ci |      1 |
+---------+----------------------+-------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And Windows-1252 [does not have a position for `U+0099`](http://i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html):

> ISO-8859-1 (also called Latin-1) is identical to Windows-1252 (also
>   called CP1252) except for the code points 128-159 (0x80-0x9F).
>   ISO-8859-1 assigns several control codes in this range. Windows-1252
>   has several characters, punctuation, arithmetic and business symbols
>   assigned to these code points.

From [West European Character Sets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-we-sets.html) in the MySQL manual:

> latin1 is the default character set. **MySQL's latin1 is the same as the
>   Windows cp1252 character set.** This means it is the same as the
>   official ISO 8859-1 or IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority)
>   latin1, except that IANA latin1 treats the code points between 0x80
>   and 0x9f as “undefined,” whereas cp1252, and therefore MySQL's latin1,
>   assign characters for those positions. For example, 0x80 is the Euro
>   sign. For the “undefined” entries in cp1252, MySQL translates 0x81 to
>   Unicode 0x0081, 0x8d to 0x008d, 0x8f to 0x008f, 0x90 to 0x0090, and
>   0x9d to 0x009d.

In short: you cannot use a `latin1` column to stored such character. Since you're already using UTF-8 in your app you should consider upgrading your database to `utf8` or, even better, `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add support for UTF-8 character set during MySQL DB schema creation, as by default schema creation sometimes it doesn't use the UTF-8 char set.

```
CREATE DATABASE dbName
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```